# Combine Knockout.js and Three.js?

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, websocket, three.js, viewmodel

I'm currently examining ways to display real-time information in 3D. In the past, I've succesfully used Knockout.js in combination with WebSockets for visualizing data in realtime with a "conventional" HTML UI.

A few days ago I started playing around with Three.js and I was surprised how easy-to-use it is. Now I thought, maybe you can bind the viewmodel to properties of certain objects in a Three.js scene? For example, binding a boolean value in the viewmodel to the visibility or color of a cube. Has anyone tried that before? How would you accomplish the binding? Are there perhaps any custom solutions?

I could start building some routines that take care of the binding, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Thanks for your comments and thoughts on this topic!

Update: I haven't mentioned the CSS3D capabilities of Three.js that would alllow data-binding because I want to avoid this technique for performance reasons and go straight for WebGL.

Comment: Rgd. combining WebGL (Three) and WebSocket in general (it's not your question, but maybe interesting anyway): http://showroomdummy.com/ - Disclosure: I created this stuff and work for Tavendo.

Comment: Looks nice! This is going into a similar direction, but in my case I have dynamically assembled objects with some thousand datapoints, so I definitely need some automated wiring-up.

Comment: @Robert did you find anything on that direction? I'm also interested in this.

Comment: Same here, just wondering how to bind instances of geometry through Knockout so I can control how they are created and handle their content. I'm building a 3D environment with content retrieved form twitter and instagram.

Comment: I didn't find a solution yet as I was busy with other projects. I'll keep the question open.